# Update one table from another without join statement

Tags: sql, firebird

I'd like to update the columns in on table based on the values of another table, I use a slightly old version of Firebird 2.1, so it doesn't have support for the join statement during update execution. In order to eliminate that, based on the instructions given in original Firebird faqs http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq323/
following statement should work, but it misses some of the values and values for that columns a returned as null as shown in the below tabular form of dataset.

For example, Num 21 from Elements table should have 23 as value in its END_I column because it has exactly the same X_I, Y_I and Z_I values with node tables, but above statement returns null .

```
update elements E set E.END_I = (select n.node_num from nodes N 
where (N.XI =E.X_I and N.YI = E.Y_I and N.ZI=E.Z_I) )
where exists (select 1 from nodes N where (N.XI =E.X_I and N.YI = E.Y_I and N.ZI=E.Z_I))
```

ELEMENTS

```
Num   End_I      End_J       X_I         Y_I        Z_I 
17  18.000000   19.000000   0.000000    1.500000    18.000000   0.000000    1.500000    21.000000
18  19.000000   20.000000   0.000000    1.500000    21.000000   0.000000    1.500000    24.000000
19  20.000000   21.000000   0.000000    1.500000    24.000000   0.000000    1.500000    27.000000
20  21.000000   22.000000   0.000000    1.500000    27.000000   0.000000    1.500000    30.000000
21  [null]      24.000000   2.400000    0.000000    0.000000    2.400000    0.000000    3.000000
22  [null]      25.000000   2.400000    0.000000    3.000000    2.400000    0.000000    6.000000
23  [null]      26.000000   2.400000    0.000000    6.000000    2.400000    0.000000    9.000000
```

NODES

```
Node_Num XI     YI          ZI
20  0.000000    1.500000    24.000000
21  0.000000    1.500000    27.000000
22  0.000000    1.500000    30.000000
23  2.400000    0.000000    0.000000
24  2.400000    0.000000    3.000000
25  2.400000    0.000000    6.000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your query as follows

```
update elements E set E.END_I = (select first 1 n.node_num from nodes N 
where (N.XI =E.X_I and N.YI = E.Y_I and N.ZI=E.Z_I) )
where exists (select 1 from nodes N where (N.XI =E.X_I and N.YI = E.Y_I and N.ZI=E.Z_I))
```

You should add `first 1` because of Firebird 2.1 doesn't know that subquery returns only one row.

Comment: I added `first 1` but result is still the same.

Comment: what if you change the first part ow your query like this: update elements E set E.END_I = 11 where exists...? Value changed as expected?

Comment: No it doesn't change values, it proves that the query never enters those and skips them ı'm using the flamerobin to run the queries btw.Executed query is : `update elements E set E.END_I = 11
where exists (select 1 from nodes N where (N.XI =E.X_I and N.YI = E.Y_I and N.ZI=E.Z_I))`

Comment: then try this: update elements E set E.END_I = (select first 1 n.node_num from nodes N 
where (N.XI =E.X_I and N.YI = E.Y_I and N.ZI=E.Z_I) )
where  (select count(n.vode_num) from nodes N where (N.XI =E.X_I and N.YI = E.Y_I and N.ZI=E.Z_I)) > 0

Comment: And one more thing - I'm not shure how firebird 2.1 compare float values. Maybe you cann't compare it like this N.XI =E.X_I, and should use some kind of workaround like N.XI-E.X_I<0.0000001

Comment: I tried that workaround also but didn't solve the issue as well, if it was that then it wouldn't even write the first values, but it writes first values then at the middle of loop skipps some of them. I would like to note that two tables doesn't have same rows , if that could be the origin of discrepancy.

Comment: Evgeny was right I'll give him the reward, problem here was : I was using the high sensitivity but actuallly lowwering the sensitivity makes it work like a charm. At the end of the day double precisions are notorious  in DB at least for Firebird.

Comment: Floating point is always suspect in comparisons, that is not specific to Firebird nor databases.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of trying to use `UPDATE`, use [`MERGE`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-merge):

```sql
merge into elements E
  using node N
  on N.XI = E.X_I and N.YI = E.Y_I and N.ZI = E.Z_I
  when matched then
    update set E.END_I = N.node_num
```

Merge allows you to use another table, view or query as source of the data to update or insert into a table.